# conda activation in Zsh

Tags: python, anaconda, zsh, conda

I use Zsh. I created `foo` by

```
conda create -n foo python=3.6
```

and I tried to activate by

```
source activate foo
```

then this is returned

```
Usage: pyenv which <command>
```

.

If I try same (`source activate foo`) in `bash`,
it works.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1371 points to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208607/zsh-export-not-valid-in-this-context/208609#208609